# Cannot make sense of values from Bluetooth HC-01

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, android

I have a simple script that listens on pin 0 for input, and if it gets anything, it `Serial.prints` it. But I cannot make sense of the results. I have a basic app that sends text over Bluetooth (in the code I see `utf8.encode(message)` if that helps), and I'm able to validate that the message is **not** corrupted by the module, by simply touching the RX and TX pins together, the app receives the same message it sent. But the Arduino cannot understand it.

Here's my code:

```cpp
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        Serial.print("New value: ");
        Serial.println(Serial.read());
    }
}
```

The TX on the HC-01 is connected to pin 0, and the RX is connected to pin 1. Power and ground are connected to the Arduino's (and I even tried different grounds just in case that one was fried). The Arduino is powered by USB and I'm using the Serial moniter. Here is some sample input-output:

```
Me through the app: a. Arduino: 255
Me through the app: a. Arduino: 254
Me through the app: a. Arduino: 254
Me through the app: a. Arduino: 254
Me through the app: a. Arduino: 254
Me through the app: a. Arduino: 255
Me through the app: aa. Arduino: 254
Me through the app: aaa. Arduino: 252
Me through the app: aaaa. Arduino: 252
```

I just don't understand any of it. Please help me out.

Comment: What is the model if the arduino you are using? On some pins 0 and 1 are also connected to the USB port connected to your PC. If this is the case you may have a conflicted usage of the port.

Comment: So should I take out the USB and just power with a battery? I can also have like an LCD print the value. Would that work?

Comment: And for reference, I'm using the latest UNO   and kept pin 1 disconnected for that reason

Comment: So how did you disconnect pin 0 from the USB? Remeber the PC will be sending a signal on this connection which will likely interfere with the signal coming in from the HC-01. Even if there is no USB activity it will still be LOW or HIGH electrically. FWIW, in your question you imply both TX and RX on the HC-01 are connected to pins 0 and 1 on the arduino. Did you try using a mega or leonardo (Serial1 for the HC-01) if you have them? Or possibly SoftwareSerial on Uno (again FWIW I have never successfully got s/w serial to work reliably but it should be ok for testing)

Comment: You may have better luck with the LCD Approach, but it will be harder to debug (no serial monitor). If you have a mega (or something else with two serial ports) life might be easier at least in the "WTF is going on here? phase you are in right now! In my case I always use my leonardo to test bluetooth, xbee and similar "Serial devices" then if appropriate move it over to Uno (cos I've got lots of them) for "production".

Comment: Yeah so I did connect both pins and experimented with unplugging pin 1. I also used SoftwareSerial on pins 10 & 11. I have a nano I could hook up... Idk if that will help since SoftwareSerial didn't work.

Comment: Glad it's not just me that has problems with it. :-) so my next suggestion would be to replicate the test where you shorted the tx and rx on the HC-01 but in software. That is, 1) connect pins 0 and 1 to tx and ex. Then 2) change your program to read `Serial.print(Serial.read());` in place of the prints you have inside the if statement. 3) To be safe, you will need to upload the program, disconnect the USB, then power your arduino via the round power connector (or if you are comfortable/brave enough) via the vin and gnd pins. Then repeat your loop back test you mentioned in your question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97182/discussion-between-gmc-and-levi-lesches).